# Could not load assembly WindowsBase after project migration from VS2015 to VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Recently I upgraded Xamarin - Android (included PCL and shared projects) from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017, all building process finishes ok with no errors, however when I tried to deploy to any mobile device in debug mode, app crashes inmediatelly. Visual Studio 2017 shows in output window following:

07-25 15:35:26.561 D/Mono ( 1768): Assembly Loader probing location: 'WindowsBase'.
07-25 15:35:26.647 F/monodroid-assembly(13855): Could not load assembly 'WindowsBase' during startup registration.
07-25 15:35:26.647 F/monodroid-assembly(13855): This might be due to an invalid debug installation.
07-25 15:35:26.647 F/monodroid-assembly(13855): A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE.

Checking windowsbase assembly, points to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\WindowsBase.dll

app installs on device but crashes.

Project always worked on Visual Studio 2015

Please your help! thanks

Comment: For what purposes do you need to use `WindowsBase` in a mobile application?

Comment: mobile application was initially developed by other engineer and he transferred knowledge to me and he's gone. Mobile app has worked fine on VS2015 but when upgraded to VS2017 it crashes. However your're right. I removed that assembly and it works fine! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WindowsBase` is an assembly for WPF exclusively. I guess it was a mistake for Xamarin to include it in the installer previously, and they correct that by removing it.

Your app should not use this assembly or its any class, and if you do use, then must migrate to other suitable API.